# Why isn't my function save_users(): working? How do I save these passwords to file?

Tags: python-3.x, function, file-writing

```py
from hashlib import sha256
import random, sys


def hash(string):
    '''Hashes a string'''

    return sha256(
        string.encode()).hexdigest() # when using hash() returns a hashed string


def save_users():
    f = open("UserDetails.txt", "w")
    f.write("Username;{} \nPassword:{}".format(username, password))
    f.close


print("\nWelcome")
signIn = input("Do you have an account? [Y/N]").upper()

if signIn == "N":
    print("Sign up :")

    username = input("New Username: ")
    password = hash(input("New Password: "))
    confirm = hash(input("ConfirmPassword: ")) == password
    print(password)

    if not confirm:
        print("Passwords do not match")

save_users()
```

"print (password)" is just there for me to test if it actually hashed the string as this is my first time doing anything like this. How would I save the password and username to an email, and similarly how would I authenticate the password and username?

Python 3.8.5

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
def save_users():
    f = open("UserDetails.txt", "w")
    f.write("Username;{} \nPassword:{}".format(username, password))
    f.close
```

With:

```
def save_users(username, password):
    f = open("UserDetails.txt", "w")
    f.write("Username;{} \nPassword:{}".format(username, password))
    f.close()
```

And call it with `save_users(username, password)` instead of `save_users()`

Answer (score -1):

```
from hashlib import sha256
def hash(string):
    '''Hashes a string'''

    return sha256(
        string.encode()).hexdigest() 


def save_users(username, password):
    with open("UserDetails.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Username;{} \nPassword:{}".format(username, password))


print("\nWelcome")
signIn = input("Do you have an account? [Y/N]").upper()

if(signIn == "N"):
    print("Sign up :")
    username = input("New Username: ")
    password = hash(input("New Password: "))
    confirm = hash(input("ConfirmPassword: ")) == password

    if(confirm):
         save_users(username, password)
    else:
        print("Passwords do not match")

else:
    print("you are already have an account")
```

Test this